# How do I boot from a live USB on an Ubuntu system?

Tags: ubuntu, live-usb, hp

I am currently using Ubuntu, but I plan to switch to Debian. My system boots directly into Ubuntu, skipping the grub boot menu. I am using an HP laptop. Can I change the boot order using BIOS? Or can I make the grub boot menu show up some other way? Either way answers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to easily boot your USB by running `systemctl reboot --firmware-setup` on Ubuntu or by spamming <kbd>F9</kbd> when your computer starts.

Also It appears your grub configuration is ordered to skip GRUB. To change that in general you can do the following:

- Run `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
- Find the line that says `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` and comment it out by adding a "#" at the beginning of that line.
- Also find the line that says `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=""`
- Write `menu` in to the quotes (if that's not already the case), so now it says

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="menu"
```

- Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>y</kbd> to save and exit.
- Update grub by using:

```
sudo update-grub
```

- If you get the error `command not found` use

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

- Reboot.

You should now be greeted by GRUB.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to boot from another disk, changing grub wont help.

You can change the boot order in BIOS, but usually there is a key to display a boot disk selecion. On HP I think it is F9...